# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, get, response

Why am I getting this error, when I'm trying to get a response from a file on my own server?

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/user.php?q=" + client + "", function(response) { 

if(response == "invalid"){
console.log("invalid login");       

    return;
}
```

And btw, the string client is mentioned already in the code.

And jquery is included.

http://i.gyazo.com/693e6633d211ab6da79598e75c6dde58.png

Comment: Did you include jQuery script in your document?

Comment: You get this error if you haven't included jQuery correctly. Please read a tutorial first: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/.

Comment: have  you included the jquery api???

Comment: Yes, it is included. Hmm

Comment: Is the `script` element for jQuery before or after the one with your code?

Comment: Before. I'm gonna try with Google's jquery library, hang on a second.. EDIT: It worked with Google's hosted jquery, it was just WP's jquery inclusion that was corrupted I think..

Comment: Try firing your code after the $(document).load

Comment: @crisbeto That's not going to help if `$` is undefined.

Comment: you're right, sorry about that

Comment: Have you tried `$ = jQuery;` or wrapping the entire function in `jQuery(document).ready( function($) { ... });`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem like this ( i have jquery loaded async so i check if is defined and then get a css...etc..)

```
<script id="jquery" type='text/javascript' async defer src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function checkJQuery(){
        if ('undefined' == typeof window.jQuery) {
            setTimeout(function(){checkJQuery();},250);
        }else{
            var css = "url-of-my-css";
            console.log("my css is loading");
            window.jQuery.get( css, function( data ) {
                $('<style>'+ data +'</style>').appendTo(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);
                console.log("css loaded");
            });

            var js = document.createElement('script'); 
            js.type = 'text/javascript';
            js.async = 'async';
            js.defer = 'defer';
            js.src = 'url-of-my-js';
            var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1];
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(js, node);
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Changing $.get to window.JQuery.get

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this in asp.net mvc 5.

```
<script>    
function OpenBulkUpload() {           
$.get("/AdminPanel/BulkUpload/Index").then(
function (r) {
$("<div id='DivBulkUpload'></div>").html(r).dialog(
{
width: 'auto', height: 'auto', modal: true, title: "Upload Pictures",
close: function () { $('#DivBulkUpload').remove(); }}); 
});
}
</script>
```

show Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in debuger browser.

solution:

1.By adding jquery UI in  package manager console

```
PM> install-package Jquery.UI.combined
```

2.And add scripts and links in top of cshtml page

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/user.php?q=" + client, function(response) { 
    if(response == "invalid"){
       console.log("invalid login"); 
       return;
    }      


});
```

Comment: Please explain how this helps if `$` is undefined?

Comment: Jquery files should be included correctly for this.<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script

Comment: That's not what you suggest in your answer though. And that's what the OP's problem is. Your answer doesn't solve the OP's problem.